# From remote machine getting connection refused for GCP Bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, gcloud-java

I am running a sample code from google to get a simple select query. Which is working fine in my local but from my k8s environment I am getting the below error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Error getting access token for service account: connect timed out
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.translate(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:115)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.create(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:220)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl$5.call(BigQueryImpl.java:369)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl$5.call(BigQueryImpl.java:366)
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:105)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:76)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.create(BigQueryImpl.java:365)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.create(BigQueryImpl.java:340)
    at com.rakuten.dps.dataplatform.ingest.utility.BQ_test.main(BQ_test.java:67)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error getting access token for service account: connect timed out
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:444)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.refresh(OAuth2Credentials.java:157)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getRequestMetadata(OAuth2Credentials.java:145)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.getRequestMetadata(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:603)
    at com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter.initialize(HttpCredentialsAdapter.java:91)
    at com.google.cloud.http.HttpTransportOptions$1.initialize(HttpTransportOptions.java:159)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory.buildRequest(HttpRequestFactory.java:88)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.buildHttpRequest(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:422)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:541)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:474)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:591)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.create(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:218)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:284)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1162)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1340)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1315)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:264)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:84)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1012)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:441)
    ... 19 more
```

Below is the sample Code:

```
public class BQ_test {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BQ_test.class);


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Job queryJob = null;
        String actualValue = "";

        NetHttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM `iconic-parsec-315409.bookmark_BQ.sbm_item_tbl``";

        String projectId = "iconic-parsec-315409";
        File credentialsPath = new File("/tmp/iconic-parsec-315409-823ef1c38a9d.json");
        GoogleCredentials credentials;
        try {
            FileInputStream serviceAccountStream = new FileInputStream(credentialsPath);
            credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccountStream);
            if (credentials.createScopedRequired()) {
                Collection<String> bigqueryScopes = BigqueryScopes.all();
                credentials = credentials.createScoped(bigqueryScopes);
            }

            BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions
                    .newBuilder()
                    .setCredentials(credentials)
                    .setProjectId(projectId)
                    .build()
                    .getService();
            QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig =
                    QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(query)
                            .setUseLegacySql(false)
                            .setJobTimeoutMs(180000L)
                            .build();
            // Create a job ID so that we can safely retry.
            JobId jobId = JobId.of(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            queryJob = bigquery.create(JobInfo.newBuilder(queryConfig).setJobId(jobId).build());
            // Wait for the query to complete.
            queryJob = queryJob.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Check for errors
        if (queryJob == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Job no longer exists");
        } else if (queryJob.getStatus().getError() != null) {
            // You can also look at queryJob.getStatus().getExecutionErrors() for all
            // errors, not just the latest one.
            throw new RuntimeException(queryJob.getStatus().getError().toString());
        }
        // Get the results.
        TableResult result = null;
        try {
            result = queryJob.getQueryResults();
            // Print all pages of the results.
           // writeFvLToOrcFile(result,"/Users/susanta.a.adhikary/Downloads/test.orc");
            for (FieldValueList row : result.iterateAll()) {
                // String type
                actualValue = row.get("sbm_item_id").getStringValue();
                System.out.println(actualValue);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I tried curl -I "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token" from my remote k8s pod and getting

HTTP/2 404
content-type: text/html
date: Sun, 04 Jul 2021 05:54:09 GMT
server: scaffolding on HTTPServer2

So I dont think its a EGRESS issue.

The Data location is US-east-1 for GCP and the pod local timezone is UTC, I am not sure if its a NTP sync issue. Need Advice. Same Code runs fine from my local with the same serviceaccount key. ( Just to mention I have done a kubectl cp to move the serviceaccount.json to the pod for testing later I'll create a configmap or something)

Comment: Did your solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63131722/google-bigquery-proxy-settings-in-java-sdk) help you with your error too?

Comment: yes It did, I was doing this to test the functionality locally with my own GCP account from my company k8s pod. Ideally in production scenario any internet connection should be disallowed and one should you dedicated interconnect.